# AWS - Amazon Connect can't establish softphone connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

below is an error message I'm getting when I try connecting with a caller. As soon as I click answer it comes up with the following:

[image: Error message]

Any ideas on how I might be able to fix this?

If you need any further information let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost always a firewall issue, the client is not being allowed to connect to TURN services outside their network.  To correct this, you will likely have to work with your network/firewall administrator to allow the traffic.  The full list of services/ports and IP address ranges are listed in the Amazon Connect documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/userguide/agentconsole-guide.html#ccp-ip-ranges).